# How to get rid of Logitech Options software recommendation dialog?

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse

I'm the administrative user on my Windows 10 computer. My wife is a strandard user.

ONLY my wife is getting this annoying nagware dialog about how wonderful it would be to install Logitech Options software. Naturally I don't want to install the suggested software.

The dialog looks like this:
[image]

I have searched up & down in task manager, but can't seem to find what process is responsible for displaying this dialog. I'm guessing it must be some kind of custom notification Windows 10 is so fond of.

Regardless, how do I get rid of this nagware?

**Edit (solution):** I removed windows\system32\LogiLDA.dll

Comment: *Task Manager* is effectively useless for this sort of thing.  Have you tried *Process Explorer*?  You may have more luck - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found that it was Windows System displaying the message, helped by some logisomething.dll. I deleted the dll and now all is fine

Comment: I deployed a registry delete action via Group Policy to delete this value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run -> Logitech Download Assistant`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Click Start
2. Type `msconfig.exe`, push enter.
3. Click the 'Startup' tab.
4. Uncheck the box next to "Logitech Download Assistant".

Comment: In windows 10, that just forwards me to task manager, startup section. But it works :)

Comment: I have windows 10 and despite that I have the "Logitech Download Assistance" as disabled I still receive annoying update notifications from Logitech options.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look in Settings > System > Notifications & actions. If Logitech is listed among notification senders you can set its notifications off.

Comment: You absolute legend. So pleased to find this tip.

Comment: This helped out

Answer (score 3):

You can use Autoruns to find it:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

This is what i had to do:

As already mentioned removed this DLL:
%systemroot%\system32\LogiLDA.dll
(**C:\Windows\system32\LogiLDA.dll**)

Then started Regedit.exe end removed the entry: "**Logitech Download Assistant**" from:
**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**

Answer (score 0):

Logitech engineers keep coming up with more creative and hacky ways to force the update and nagging pop ups. With the new versions, removing the dll file or the registry key no longer works as those they keep getting reinstated by the software or the driver updates.

I still want some of the functionality of the software, to define and remap actions of the extra mouse buttons, but I don't want all the nagware and pop ups that they keep adding in the newer versions.

So for my case, the best solution I found so far is to install an old and cleaner version of logitech options (7.12) and prevent it in the firewall from accessing the internet to get updates.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling it via process explorer \ msconfig won't help, because there is other exe file which is launching other logi executables, what you need to do is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns
Select there "Download Autoruns and Autorunsc" a trusted software link from Microsoft.

Then in "Autoruns" app find entry called "OptionsPlusUpdaterService" this is what starts all Logi other executables, disable it and restart computer. Logi should be gone from autostart.